# Finding holes in 2d point cloud

Tags: python, geometry, 2d, computational-geometry, point-clouds

I have a set of 2d points. They are X,Y coordinates on a standard Cartesian grid system. Does anyone know a way to implement (preferentially in Python) an algorithm that will isolate each "hole's area" in order to find the largest diameter for each hole.

Below  an example of actual point sets :

[image]

**UPDATE :**

I managed to isolate each area with a fixed number of clusters, but how can I define the number of clusters according to number of "hole's area" ?

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import  ipyvolume.pylab as p

dat     = xyz
xycoors = dat[:,0:2]


fit = KMeans(n_clusters=5).fit(xycoors)
clus_datas={i: xycoors[np.where(fit.labels_ == i)] for i in 
range(fit.n_clusters)}

clus_1=clus_datas[0]
clus_2=clus_datas[1]
clus_3=clus_datas[2]
clus_4=clus_datas[3]
clus_5=clus_datas[4]



min_bloc=np.array(nuage)
fig = p.figure(width=1000)
fig.xlabel='x'
fig.ylabel='z'
fig.zlabel='y'

p.scatter(clus_1[:,1], clus_1[:,1]*0, clus_1[:,0], color="black", size=.1)     
p.scatter(clus_2[:,1], clus_2[:,1]*0, clus_2[:,0], color="red",  size=.1) 
p.scatter(clus_3[:,1], clus_3[:,1]*0, clus_3[:,0], color="green",  size=.1) 
p.scatter(clus_4[:,1], clus_1[:,1]*0, clus_4[:,0], color="bleu",  size=.1)     
p.scatter(clus_5[:,1], clus_2[:,1]*0, clus_5[:,0], color="red", size=.1) 

p.squarelim()
p.show()
```

Results : 
[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain the relationship between "will find the largest diameter for each hole" and the set of 2d points? It looks like your screenshot has some red circles. Are you just trying to find the inner diameter of these?

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I need

Comment: Lookup the "Maximum inscribed circle" problem, which is what you want to address. Notice that you need to isolate the clusters for this. And IMO,  this will be a very poor estimate of the diameter of the holes due to the noise.

Comment: @YvesDaoust how can I define the number of clusters according to number of "hole's area" ?

Comment: @bestyasser: sorry, don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How I can estimate  the number of clusters that I need to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**
[Density-based spatial clustering of applications with noise (DBSCAN)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSFd6UHjxII) Identify each hole according to estimated  number of clusters, the diameter can be calculated using the [Convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)